# Open_basedir restriction in effect - how to get rid of error?

Tags: php, windows, plesk

I am getting these errors - as far as I can figure out, it appears to be relating to a PHP rule or something with my vhosts.

I'm finding very little on how to solve it.

Basically we're trying to set up a preview/development site for a live site, and getting these errors. The site is a Drupal site (PHP, MySQL-based), on a Windows server.

How do I get rid of this error and make the preview site work?

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5http://preview.domain.com/includes/bootstrap.inc) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:/Inetpub/vhosts/domain.com\;C:\windows\Temp\) in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\preview.domain.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 21

Warning: require_once(C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5http://preview.domain.com/includes/bootstrap.inc) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\preview.domain.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 21

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5http://preview.domain.com/includes/bootstrap.inc' (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\preview.domain.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 21
```

Comment: "open_basedir restriction in effect" i dont know what more to say (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue not in open_basedir, but in this path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5http://preview.domain.com/includes/bootstrap.inc"

What happens in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\preview.domain.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 21 ?

Comment: require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc'; is what happens. For some reason, it seems to append DRUPAL_ROOT (http://preview.domain.com/includes/bootstrap.inc) to this plesk directory.

Comment: So, root cause of your issue is wrong path defined in constant DRUPAL_ROOT. To understand what actually happens with DRUPAL_ROOT  you should check index.php for string like "define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());" it's a default way how drupal understand where he's installed. Maybe you have some customization in index.php file, because it's actually strange how getcwd() can return such strange path(as in error message). As workaround, you can hardcode path to drupal which will be like "C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\preview.domain.com\httpdocs".